# Normalization two types of customers into one table

Tags: database-design

I am trying to model a sales situation where you can sell to a person or to a business with a contact person. I cannot figure out the proper way to do this.

It seems like 2 tables would be incorrect. But how do I model a `Customer` table that can be a business or a person? Would I just have a `boolean` for "business" and an additional "business_name" field that would default to Null. But then I have to do an if/then on the columns and that seems like poor design.

Any advice, direction, or links is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4690648/562459) deals specifically with individuals and organizations. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4690648/562459) uses the same technique in a slightly different application.

Answer (score 0):

For some detailed explanation of two design alternatives and a related technique,  google articles on "Single Table Inheritance", "Class Table Inheritance" and "Shared Primary Key".

There are tags for all three of these here in SO as well.